# With ansible.posix.synchronize, is there a way to a source folder that may not exist?

Tags: ansible

```
tasks:
    - name: sync folders
      loop: "{{ folder_list | list }}"
      ansible.posix.synchronize:
        src: "/path/folder/{{ item }}"
        dest: "/other_node/folders/"
        archive: false
        recursive: true
        perms: true
        checksum: true
        delete: true
```

- The list of folders `folder_list` is defined somewhere else.
- I do not have control of this, and cannot change it. I also do not know the folder list up front, so cannot set it statically.
- It may contain items that do not exist on "this" machine.

Is there a way to have the sync task skip such `item`s? I found `stat`. Looks like it can be used to check for the existence of a file or folder, but I couldn't figure out how to use it,  `set_fact`, and `synchronize` together within the task to accomplish this.

What I'm trying to do is something like:

Loop through folder list > if source folder exists > sync folder to destination.

PS: Please let me know if this belongs on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [testing paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths) on the controller is simple. For example, given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/export/
/tmp/export/
├── dir1
│   ├── a
│   └── b
└── dir2
    └── c

2 directories, 3 files
```

The playbook below skips missing folders

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_11

  vars:

    folder_list:
      - /tmp/export/dir1
      - /tmp/export/dir2
      - /tmp/export/dir3

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "synchronize {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ folder_list }}"
      when: item is directory
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [test_11] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => (item=/tmp/export/dir1) => 
  msg: synchronize /tmp/export/dir1
ok: [test_11] => (item=/tmp/export/dir2) => 
  msg: synchronize /tmp/export/dir2
skipping: [test_11] => (item=/tmp/export/dir3) 

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can combine the conditions. For example,

```yaml
      when: item is directory or item is link
```

, or simply test the existence only

```yaml
      when: item is exists
```

---

Note: The module [*stat*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#ansible-builtin-stat-module-retrieve-file-or-file-system-status) examines the files at the current host. You have to delegate this task to *localhost* if you want to use it here. Register the results and declare the variable below

```yaml
  folder_exists: "{{ dict(folder_list_stat.results|
                          json_query('[].[item, stat.exists]')) }}"
```

```yaml
    - block:

        - stat:
            path: "{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{ folder_list }}"
          register: folder_list_stat
    
        - debug:
            var: folder_list_stat
          when: debug|d(false)|bool

        - debug:
            var: folder_exists
          when: debug|d(false)|bool

      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives the dictionary

```yaml
  folder_exists:
    /tmp/export/dir1: true
    /tmp/export/dir2: true
    /tmp/export/dir3: false
```

Then, the condition is trivial. See the debug on what other attributes are available in *folder_list_stat* and create other dictionaries for testing if you want to.

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: test_11

  vars:

    folder_list:
      - /tmp/export/dir1
      - /tmp/export/dir2
      - /tmp/export/dir3

    folder_exists: "{{ dict(folder_list_stat.results|
                            json_query('[].[item, stat.exists]')) }}"
    
  tasks:

    - block:
        - stat:
            path: "{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{ folder_list }}"
          register: folder_list_stat
    
        - debug:
            var: folder_list_stat
          when: debug|d(false)|bool
        - debug:
            var: folder_exists
          when: debug|d(false)|bool
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "synchronize {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ folder_list }}"
      when: folder_exists[item]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up using a combination of your original "item is directory" check and the full playbook (instead of the stat/json_query).